# Adding a list element if it is absent in a comparison of two lists

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have example data as follows:

```
DT1 <- structure(list(Province = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Year = c(2000, 
2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2002, 2002, 2002), Municipality = c("Something", "Anything", 
"Nothing", "Something", "Anything", "Nothing", "Something", "Anything", 
"Nothing", "Something", "Anything", "Nothing", "Something", "Anything", 
"Nothing", "Something", "Anything", "Nothing", "Something", "Anything", 
"Nothing", "Something", "Anything", "Nothing", "Something", "Anything", 
"Nothing"), Values = c(0.59, 0.58, 0.66, 0.53, 0.94, 0.2, 0.86, 
0.85, 0.99, 0.59, 0.58, 0.66, 0.53, 0.94, 0.2, 0.86, 0.85, 0.99, 
0.59, 0.58, 0.66, 0.53, 0.94, 0.2, 0.86, 0.85, 0.99)), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

DT2 <- structure(list(Province = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Year = c(2000, 
2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2002, 2002, 2002), Municipality = c("Some", "Anything", 
"Nothing", "Someth.", "Anything", "Not", "Something", "Anything", 
"None", "Some", "Anything", "Nothing", "Someth.", "Anything", 
"Not", "Something", "Anything", "None", "Some", "Anything", "Nothing", 
"Someth.", "Anything", "Not", "Something", "Anything", "None"
), `Other Values` = c(0.41, 0.42, 0.34, 0.47, 0.0600000000000001, 
0.8, 0.14, 0.15, 0.01, 0.41, 0.42, 0.34, 0.47, 0.0600000000000001, 
0.8, 0.14, 0.15, 0.01, 0.41, 0.42, 0.34, 0.47, 0.0600000000000001, 
0.8, 0.14, 0.15, 0.01)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
DT2 <- DT2[-c(5:10),]

DT1_list <- DT1%>%
  group_split(Province, Year)

DT2_list <- DT2%>%
  group_split(Province, Year)
```

The "subframes" in `DT1_list` and `DT2_list` are split out by `Province, Year`, but they do no match.
For the operation I want to do, I need them to match. I was thinking about using a `for-loop` to insert a subframe, whenever the `Province, Year` of the subframe of `DT1_list` does not match the subframe of `DT2_list` , but I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
for (i in 1:9) {
  if (DT1_list[[i]][[Province, Year]] != DT2_list[[i]][[Province, Year]]) {
    DT2_list[[i]] <- "Put a list with the province and year in between"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to put the list with other values blank in between?

Comment: Yes, everything should be blank, except for `Province, Year`.

Comment: See the solution proposed based on `tidyverse` approach instead of using the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify smaller DF like this

```
library(tidyverse)

DT2_modified <- DT1 %>% select(Province, Year) %>% group_by(Province, Year) %>% 
  slice_head() %>%
  left_join(DT2, by = c("Province", "Year"))

#Now extract your lists
DT2_list_modified <- DT2_modified %>%
  group_split(Province, Year)


#Check the code/result
> DT2_list_modified
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    Province    : double
    Year        : double
    Municipality: character
    Other Values: double
  >
>[9]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Province  Year Municipality `Other Values`
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1        1  2000 Some                   0.41
2        1  2000 Anything               0.42
3        1  2000 Nothing                0.34

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Province  Year Municipality `Other Values`
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1        1  2001 Someth.                0.47

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Province  Year Municipality `Other Values`
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1        1  2002 NA                       NA

[[4]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Province  Year Municipality `Other Values`
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1        2  2000 Anything               0.42
2        2  2000 Nothing                0.34

[[5]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Province  Year Municipality `Other Values`
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1        2  2001 Someth.                0.47
2        2  2001 Anything               0.06
3        2  2001 Not                    0.8 

[[6]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Province  Year Municipality `Other Values`
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1        2  2002 Something              0.14
2        2  2002 Anything               0.15
3        2  2002 None                   0.01

[[7]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Province  Year Municipality `Other Values`
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1        3  2000 Some                   0.41
2        3  2000 Anything               0.42
3        3  2000 Nothing                0.34

[[8]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Province  Year Municipality `Other Values`
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1        3  2001 Someth.                0.47
2        3  2001 Anything               0.06
3        3  2001 Not                    0.8 

[[9]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Province  Year Municipality `Other Values`
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1        3  2002 Something              0.14
2        3  2002 Anything               0.15
3        3  2002 None                   0.01
```

I think this will serve the purpose

Comment: Thank you very much! I am checking it on my actual data right now.